# Ruby Cucumber Automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, capybara, bdd

We are doing automation using `Ruby` and `Cucumber`. We have around 80 feature files, 1 web_Steps file containing all the generic steps.
The problem we are facing is all locators are present in the feature file. So if the html structure changes then we have to update the locators in all the respective files which is very time consuming. eg:
web step:

```
And /^I fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/ do |field, value|
 fill_in(field, with: value)
end
```

Feature file:

```
And I fill in "location" with "Mumbai"
And I fill in "contact_details" with "xxx@gmail.com"
```

So if the locator "location" changed to something else then we have to update all the feature files which contains the locator "location"

Is there any better way to tackle this problem?.

Comment: I don't know if I really understood your question. But, If I do: can't you create a global variable `$locator = 'location'` ? So you'll only have to change it and it'll change in all the feature files.

Comment: Also if you have many of these changeable variables create a global hash and store the locators with a suitable key in them.

Comment: Are you using page objects? if not, you should.

Answer (score 1):

Basically "You're cuking it wrong" -  The type of tests you have are exactly why web_steps.rb was removed from cucumber a few years ago.  The following article goes into how tests should be written when using cucumber - http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off

Answer (score 0):

I'd add in your `spec_helper.rb` a global variable

```
$locator = 'location'
```

In case the HTML changes, you will be easily able to change it only once in your `spec_helper` and the locator will change in all your feature files.

Comment: I am not able to understand how can my websteps will understand which global variable to pick.
Can you give some reference sites for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of great articles already on the topic, but I really like this [push HOW down](http://www.marcusoft.net/2013/04/PushTheHowDown.html). To sum it up:

> - favor declarative BDD
> - refactor to introduce DSL
> - move all UI sensitive details (e.g. selectors) to single source of truth in your code

Patterns like [Loadable component](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/selenium-webdriver-practical/9781782168850/ch09s04.html),  [Page object](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/) and [Object map](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/ui-map-object-repository-using-properties-file) will help you with all this.

Answer (score 0):

[This is our exisitng structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krub4.png)

[This is something i am thinking of, by creating multiple web_steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2zK8.png)

I know that the page object model is something i should follow but it will take substantial amount of time.
The other idea using global variable, i had never done it but as of now this is something looks feasible.